# Google Maps API: condition on Marker color

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to put conditions on the colors of the Google Maps Markers .

I tried something like:

```
        if (name == 'name') {

        icon: image2

        }
```

But the Map dosent show anymore and I dont know how to debug it.

Here is the full script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function load() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?= json_encode($lat); ?>, <?= json_encode($lng);?>),
    zoom: <?php echo json_encode($zoom); ?>,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
  downloadUrl(<?= json_encode($url); ?>, function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
      //var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      var image1 = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png';
      var image2 = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png';

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,


     if (name == 'name') {

        icon: image2

        }

      });

      hover(marker,i);
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);

    }
  });
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);

  });
}

function hover(marker, i){
document.getElementById('a'+i).onmouseover = function() {
   marker.setIcon('http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png');
}
document.getElementById('a'+i).onmouseleave = function() {
   marker.setIcon('http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png');
}
}


function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };


  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}


function doNothing() {}
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: browsers have developer tools with a console that shows errors, like the fact that you have invalid javascript ... i.e. what you've tried is not valid javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with this approach:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
});

 if (name == 'name') {
 marker.setIcon('image2');
}
else{
 marker.setIcon('image1');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this approach works great! I am also using a hover function (I edited the post) that changes the icon when I have mouse over a division. Now on mouseleave I just get back to one color and loose the color set before hover. What approach would be best to make the color of icon go back to the condition set initially ?

Comment: The approach you tried in a code should work...I haven't tried it still

Comment: Thanks. With this code it works to modifiy the Markers on mouseover and mouseleave. But instead of only one color Marker in mouseleave I'd like to go back to the intial setting of the condition. I would try something like document.getElementById('a'+i).onmouseleave = function() {
                 if (name == 'name') {
                 marker.setIcon('imagebeforehover');
}  but name is not defined anymore out of the loop.